# Producing density map in square kilometers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, density

I have a shp file with the location (lat, lon) of lightning spatial distribution. I want to produce a density map of lightning occurrence per square KM. I used density point function and I don't know how to transform the output in square KM.

My map's unit is kilometer do should I use 1 Km radius?

I'm using ArcMap 9.3.

Answer (score 6):

Choose *square kilometres* for the *area units* parameter in the density tool. Then your result raster is *lightnig per square kilometer*. You do not have to transform anything.

The *search radius* is independent of the *area units* parameter. Larger values of the radius parameter produce a smoother, more generalized density raster. Smaller values produce a raster that shows more detail.